# How do I add a custom ImageView to Android?

Tags: android

I want to add a Google Drive Logo to a RelativeLayout next to a button in XML, but I don't know how. Can anyone help?

Comment: What have yo tried so far?  You're much more likely to get help if you post your attempt at a solution for people to provide feedback on.  See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

Wow...

1.) Add a ImageView
2.) Use the `src` attribute or thr `setImageDrawable` method

Comment: Yeah, but I need an image from online as my ImageView.